# What cross-language messaging protocols are included in WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: java, jms, websphere, mqtt, websphere-liberty

This [article](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_rtcomm.html) talks about IBM WebSphere Liberty WebRTC support via MQTT over the rtcomm library.

I am interested in exchanging messages between Java EE JMS (queue / topic) destinations on WebSphere Liberty and clients which are written in other languages.

Is it possible to connect from clients to WebSphere Liberty over MQTT and exchange messages with JMS destinations?

Does WebSphere Liberty support other cross-language messaging protocols such as AMQP or STOMP?

Comment: 1) MQTT is a protocol meant for constrained devices such as sensors. I doubt it'll be useful for point-to-point messaging. 2) Liberty supports JMS. As long as you have an interface between your target protocol and JMS, you should be able to make use of the protocol. 3) If you can consider a product-based solution, try [IBM Integration Bus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ah36080_.htm), which can transform messages on the fly.

Comment: @XSurgent many thanks! This answered my questions with 1: none 2: only with extra coding 3: no ;)

Comment: Happy to help. Should I expand my comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of messaging, WebSphere Liberty supports JMS, as documented [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_messaging.html):

> Liberty supports asynchronous messaging as a method of communication that is based on the Java™ Message Service (JMS) programming interface. The JMS interface provides a common way for Java programs (clients and Java EE applications) to create, send, receive, and read asynchronous requests as JMS messages.

Therefore, Liberty does not implement the MQTT protocol (or any other messaging protocol) by itself. It makes use of the protocol using an intermediary. In a similar manner, any messaging protocol can be implemented by Liberty provided that there is a JMS interface to access and manipulate messages transmitted using the said protocol.

In the linked article that is part of the question, this is done by the 'MQTT Message Broker' component. Two examples in the article are:

1. IBM MessageSight - An appliance-based messaging server.
2. WebSphere MQ Telemetry - A service that runs on a WebSphere MQ server.

Using the WebSphere MQ Telemetry service with the MQTT protocol is detailed in the IBM Redbook : [Building Smarter Planet Solutions with MQTT and IBM WebSphere MQ Telemetry](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248054.html?Open).

The MQTT protocol itself has been designed to support constrained devices. To quote:

> The MQTT messaging protocol is designed for devices in constrained environments, such as embedded systems with limited processing ability and memory or systems that are connected to unreliable networks.

In addition, MQTT relies on a Publish/Subscribe model, and does not offer point-to-point messaging.

For the language-independent messaging requirement mentioned in the question, you can consider a product-based solution, which is an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB). ESBs are used to route, transform and manipulate messages in-transit between communicating systems.

Examples of commercial ESBs are IBM Integration Bus, Oracle Enterprise Service Bus and SAP Process Integration. Open-source alternatives include Apache Camel, JBoss ESB and Mule ESB.

Answer (score 0):

Every JMS connection requires a JMS Provider - something that your JMS code connects to.

Depending on what that provider is, you can connect to that provider from other languages.  The JMS provider has to give non-JMS interfaces for those other languages.

As an example, you can use IBM MQ or AMQP or etc as a JMS Provider and then use the interfaces supplied by MQ or AMQP or etc to connect from other languages like python or ruby or whatever languages that JMS provider supports.

The only MQTT protocol server that I know of that also has a JMS interface is IBM IOT MessageSight.  It gives you both pub/sub and queue based support.  But the queue based support is only available from the MessageSight JMS interface.